# How do I make the search bar bigger?

Tags: html, css

This is the code I have so far and I want to know how to make the search bar fit the navigation bar right. Help, please and sorry i'm not really good at coding this is for a Information Technology class i'm taking.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #8A1414;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Movies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">TV</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <input id="search-bar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <input id="search-button" name="search_submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can only have `li` as children of a `ul`. **Validate your code!**

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. You can only have `li` as children of a `ul`

So we need to make some changes.

I'd suggest something like:

We take the search inputs out of the `ul` where they don't belong. Wrap those in their own div and float that to the right.

Wrap the whole lot (`ul` and search div) in a `nav` element.

Set the `search` input to `display:inline-block` then apply any width you'd like.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KzJGEW)

```css
nav {
  background-color: #8A1414;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.search {
  float: right;
  padding: 14px 0;
}
.search #search-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  /* your width here */
  /* 100px for SO Snippet only */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">Movies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">TV</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="search">
    <input id="search-bar" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <input id="search-button" name="search_submit" type="submit" value="Search">
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?Put in your css code this:

```
input#search-bar {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set increase the width put this in the css/ style tag

```
#search-bar{ width: 300px }
```

You can tweak the values according to your preferance.

If you want to properly adjust search bar in the layout, I can suggest following properties and you can also tweak their values.

```
#search-bar{
             width: 300px;
             height: 20px;
             margin-top: 10px;
             margin-left: 600px; 
           }
```

You should visit w3c school website for better understanding of CSS and HTML.

Comment: You can also use Floats but that depends on your level of understanding.